Reverse engineer the stationary distribution of a Markov Chain (is my code related to MCMC?)
The MATLAB code below generates a sample from an unknown distribution using a simple rule. I'm trying to figure out an analytical expression for the density function of the generated sample.
Right now, I'm in the mud trying to figure out the mathematical machinery needed for describing this statistical procedure in hopes I can reverse engineer the analytical expression for the sample distribution.
At first, this reminded me of rejection sampling but I think this is the wrong direction since the accepted samples are correlated.  My next thought is that the procedure described in my code looks similar to MCMC...we seed with an initial value to create a Markov chain that converges to some stationary distribution.  Typically in MCMC we start with a target distribution and construct a Markov chain with stationary distribution equal to the target distribution.  Here the process is in reverse: we have a Markov chain and want to understand what the stationary distribution is.
My current idea is to try to force this problem to look like an implementation of Metropolis Hastings algorithm to deduce the stationary distribution but have not made much progress.  Any suggestion on how to proceed would be helpful.
% simulation parameters
th_on = 0.5;
th_off = 2;
sigma = 0.5;

% initial value
V = normrnd(0,sigma);

sample = [];
for j = 1:1e6
 X = normrnd(0,sigma); % generate a proposal
 if X-V>=th_on || X-V<=-th_off % accept proposal if condition is met
     V = X;
     sample = [sample V];
 else
    % if condition is not met, reject proposal 
 end
end

Histogram of the sample:

